# Deploy in Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

I am new to Java development and recently developed a website for a client.

Now i need to publish on the Internet. The hosting company provides Tomcat 7 and i have to put the WAR via FTP and restart the application from their control panel.

The site offers file upload feature. I save the files in the application folder and at database i save only the path as a string.

My question is: the next time I will deploy the app with the new version, all these files and images that were saved via upload will be deleted? The new WAR, after explodes, erases any previous contents?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the deployment process of your provider, but I think it will erase the contents. Put the contents outside the Tomcat directory, i.e. /var/data/appname, give your servers user access rights and define that directory in your app, using a context file, JNDI or a simple constant.